# why mapreduce doesn't get launched when using hadoop fs -put command?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Please excuse me for this basic question. 
But I wonder why mapreduce job don't get launched when we try to load some file having size more than the block size.

Somewhere I learnt that MapReduce will take care of loading the datasets from LFS to HDFS. Then why I am not able to see mapreduce logs on the console when I give hadoop fs -put command?

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of hadoop distcp which will spawn a MapReduce job.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html

> DistCp Version 2 (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra cluster copying. It uses MapReduce to effect its distribution, error  handling and recovery, and reporting. It expands a list of files and directories into input to map tasks, each of which will copy a partition of the files specified in the source list.

`hadoop fs -put` or `hdfs dfs -put` are implemented entirely by HDFS and don't require MapReduce.