# Is there any role of mappers or reducers while running HDFS commands?

Tags: hadoop

Ex: hdfs fs -ls /
    hdfs fs put

If yes then how and if no then how it works in back end?

Comment: Did you already look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471123/why-mapreduce-doesnt-get-launched-when-using-hadoop-fs-put-command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why mapreduce doesn't get launched when using hadoop fs -put command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471123/why-mapreduce-doesnt-get-launched-when-using-hadoop-fs-put-command)

Comment: Not all HDFS actions require mapreduce. Just like not all HTTP requests are rendered to webpages. And not all HDFS actions even need a reduce phase

Comment: Can i know which all commnads use MapReduce??